# In VS Code: Red (stop running script) square button disappeared

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This happened to me: For years had a green "play" button at top right of screen to run my python script. When running (**not in debug mode**), a red square "stop" button would be in that spot that I could press to cause my code to stop running. Just today I was installing VS Code on a client's machine and the stop button does not appear.

Clue: When I was trying to pip install the pyodbc library, it errored out, saying I needed to install some C++ stuff. I may have installed the wrong stuff or too much. BUT it was then able to pip install pyodbc so I let it go. But now I have no stop button AND script output now goes to the terminal tab at bottom of VS Code instead of the Output tab.

Ideas?

Comment: What version of VS Code are you running? On 1.78 I have a "Play" button in the upper-right of my screen that says "Run Python File" when I hover over it (and FWIW, it's an outline - not green). Does that client have the Python extension installed?

Comment: What extension were you using? The Python extension doesn't put script output in the Output tab AFAIK. Were you using [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner#Configuration)?

Comment: To expand on @wjandrea's comment - you don't really even need Code Runner any more; at least not for Python...not sure if that helps any

Comment: Thanks, guys, for taking the time to brainstorm! (1) VS Code x64 on Windows 10, 1.83; (2) Yes, Python extension; (3) Tried with and without Code Runner, no difference seen.

Comment: I have a feeling this is actually related to CodeRunner. After you disabled CodeRunner, did you reload/restart VS Code? If not, try reloading. The stop button should be gone. Then enable CodeRunner and reload and I think the stop button will be there during running a script. See also https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aformulahendry%2Fvscode-code-runner%20stop&type=code and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136570

Answer (score 1):

You must be using *Code Runner* and executing the script using the `Run Code` option. This is not recommended.

[image]

You should use the official extension **Python** to execute the script (`Run Python File`).

[image]

As an answer to the question: *Code Runner* brings up what you call the red square notification button.

Comment: Thanks! If I use the recommended route (No red stop button), what is the best way to manually stop the script?

Comment: If you need the terminal to execute the process, it is best to choose debugging. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging